# R code is running using data.frame function, however, cannot be knitted to pdf

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Hello helpful coders,
I am having problems knitting this code to a pdf, because apparently the object is not found.
Attached you can see the code and the error message attached as a link:

```
set.seed(1)
data.frame(number = 1:100, 
           x = rnorm(n=100, mean=50, sd=2),
           u = rnorm(n=100, mean=0, sd=1),
           y = 20 -2*x + u)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7eTV.png

Please help.

Comment: You are referring to `x` and `u` in the definition of `y`, but they haven't been created in your workspace, they are columns in the dataframe.  The `data.frame()` function uses simple well-defined rules for scoping, not the wild west rules used by some tidyverse functions.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new to stack, can I give you a positive rating or something?

Comment: You could click on the up-arrow beside the comment, but there's no need to do that.